# how to get the download path using VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript, download, special-folders

I need to get the download path of a desktop using vbscript.
 So I need a syntax like

`MyDoc = Ws.SpecialFolders("Mydocuments")`.

Have you any idea ??

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
Dim sDesktopPath
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sDesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```